# Show activity of an Azure repository on Github Profile Activity

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

Since Microsoft bought GitHub, is it possible count activity for your GitHub profile when you commit to an azure repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since Microsoft bought GitHub, is it possible count activity for your
> GitHub profile when you commit to an azure repository?

**I think you cannot get what you want.**

**Microsoft** just bought the forum business of **GitHub**, which itself and **Azure Devops** are two different products.

And **Azure Devops** currently does not integrate this functionality - mapping git activity information for the project to repository.

**So I am afraid that you cannot get what you want.**

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension, [Contributions Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.contributions).